# I'm getting an odd number of class, interface, or enum expected error codes even though everything appears to be in order?

Tags: java

I am working with inheritance in java and was tasked with creating several different classes that all work together in my Driver file to detail a travel course, keeping track of its credit number, instructor, destination, catalog number, title, and section number.  I keep getting several of the same error (class, interface, or enum expected) in several of my files however, and no matter how I switch up the syntax I am not sure what I am doing wrong?  I tried to put the curly brackets directly underneath whatever needs it (this has seemed to solve the problem before in Eclipse but has not worked the same in GitBash).  Below I put two of my sections of code that are giving me trouble.

```
public class TravelCourse extends Course {
    static String destination;
    
public TravelCourse() 
{
    
}


public static String destinationNew() {
    return destination;
}

public static void setdestinationNew(String destination) {
    TravelCourse.destination = destination;
    
}

TravelCourse(String destination){
    
}

public String getDestinationNew() {
    return destination;
}

public void setDestinationNew(String destination) {
    TravelCourse.destination = destination;
}
}
```

These are the errors I keep getting for this file specifically

```
TravelCourse.java:4: error: <identifier> expected
        public TravelCourse
                           ^
TravelCourse.java:8: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public static String destinationNew()
                      ^
TravelCourse.java:11: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
TravelCourse.java:13: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public static void setDestinationNew(String destination){
                      ^
TravelCourse.java:15: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
TravelCourse.java:20: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public String getDestinationNew(){
               ^
TravelCourse.java:22: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
TravelCourse.java:24: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public void setDestinationNew(String destination){
               ^
TravelCourse.java:26: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
```

The other file that keeps throwing the same error is below as well, with the errors directly following it.

```
public class TravelCourseSection extends TravelCourse{
    static int sectionNumber;
    static String instructor;
    
    
TravelCourseSection(int sectionNumber, String instructor){
    TravelCourseSection.sectionNumber = sectionNumber;
    TravelCourseSection.instructor = instructor;
    
}

public int getSectionNumberNew() {
    return sectionNumber;
}

public void setSectionNumberNew(int sectionNumber) {
    TravelCourseSection.sectionNumber = sectionNumber;
}


public String setInstructor() {
    return instructor;

}

public void getInstructor(String instructor) {
    TravelCourseSection.instructor = instructor;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
        return "Section Number:" + sectionNumber + "%nInstructor:" + instructor;
}
}
```

Errors

```
./TravelCourse.java:4: error: <identifier> expected
        public TravelCourse
                           ^
./TravelCourse.java:8: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public static String destinationNew()
                      ^
./TravelCourse.java:11: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
./TravelCourse.java:13: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public static void setDestinationNew(String destination){
                      ^
./TravelCourse.java:15: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
./TravelCourse.java:20: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public String getDestinationNew(){
               ^
./TravelCourse.java:22: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
./TravelCourse.java:24: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public void setDestinationNew(String destination){
               ^
./TravelCourse.java:26: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
```

Comment: Just a side note and not addressing your actual problem (at least not the one you're asking about): you definitely should look into the use of constructors, the `static` keyword (so class vs. instance level fields and methods) as well as your naming conventions (e.g. `String setInstructor()` and `void getInstructor(String)` - that's confusing and will likely cause errors).

Comment: Also: "I keep getting several of the same error (class, interface, or enum expected)" - ideally you should actually post those errors, i.e. the stacktraces - and mark the lines of your code that they are refering to. I can't spot any obvious syntax problem so it's hard to help without more information, ideally a [mcve]. My guess would be that the source of your error is in the `Course` class or `Course` is an interface and thus need to use `implements` instead of `extends`.

Comment: @Thomas Is that what you meant by include the errors?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Note that it would be good to also mark the lines that are mentioned in those errors. In your case it's fairly easy to identify the first lines but that's not always the case and at least I won't start counting lines to find those with higher numbers. Besides that, are you _sure_ the code you've posted for `TravelCourse.java` is _all_ the code and what's being compiled? Did you check that it only contains ASCII characters (unicode might contain some that look the same but are different).

Comment: Is Course in your import statements or is it in the same package? Also, was it compiled first?